# Professional Edition - Record Types Limitations (ISV AppExchange App Development)

Tags: appexchange, professional-edition, oem

We are developing an AppExchange App (ISV/OEM).

For AppExchange Apps to be installed on Professional Edition. We can't use Record Types in past, seems now its possible, based on this ISVForce Guide document >
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm

I read somewhere that Lightning Professional Edition only allows 3 record types, does this impacts AppExchange apps as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't have a problem. Once certified (passed security review), your app no longer counts towards normal limits, including apps, objects, fields, and so on. They'll even be able to create new record types assuming they haven't reached their limit, even if your package includes record types.

Comment: Is external id fields still counted in aggregate? IIRC managed external ids counted along with subscriber external ids. Any other important cases where this would be true?

Comment: @Eric I believe the aggregates are the same as they always were: External ID, Rollup Summary fields, and formula compiled limit sizes. The documentation suggests that the first two can be increased if there's a business purpose for it.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox - this means we can create more than 3 record types in our managed package, and it should work well post security review ?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta The documentation calls out (most) limits, so this seems to be a matter of confirmation by omission. To be absolutely sure, I would consider logging a case with Partner Support and see what they say.